# Child list for field salesreport cannot be created

Tags: vb.net

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdOk.Click
    Dim scan As String = "select ProductCode from products where ProductCode = '" & TextBox1.Text & "';"
    connection.Open()
    Dim cmd = New MySqlCommand(scan, connection)
    Dim dr As MySqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
    If dr.Read = True Then
        MsgBox("Match found")
        connection.Close()
        Dim insert As String = "insert into salesreport (ProductName,ProductPrice) select products.ProductName,products.ProductPrice from products where products.ProductCode = '" & TextBox1.Text & "';"
        connection.Open()
        da = New MySqlDataAdapter(insert, connection)
        da.Fill(ds, "salesreport")
        DataGridView1.DataSource = ds
        DataGridView1.DataMember = "salesreport"
        connection.Close()
    Else
        connection.Close()
        MsgBox("No match found")
        TextBox1.Text = ""
        TextBox1.Select()
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Please edit your question and format the code to make it readable

Answer (score 0):

**INSERT** statements doesn't return records.
There is no sense in this situation to use a DataAdapter to INSERT a record.

Use the MySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery method to insert your record, then read the added row with a MySqlDataAdapter

Also, do not concatenate text, **typed by your user**, to build and use an sql text for the database engine. Your code could be easily used to create [Sql Injection Attacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13331167/child-list-for-field-salesreport-cannot-be-created).

```
    Dim scan As String = "select ProductCode from products " + 
                         "where ProductCode = ?prodCode"
    connection.Open()
    Dim cmd = New MySqlCommand(scan, connection)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?prodCode", TextBox1.Text)
    ..........

    Dim insert As String = "insert into salesreport (ProductName,ProductPrice) " + 
                "select products.ProductName,products.ProductPrice from products " +
                "where products.ProductCode = ?prodCode"

    cmd = new MySqlCommand(insert, connection)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?prodCode", TextBox1.Text)
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() 

    da = New MySqlDataAdapter(scan, connection)
    da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("?prodCode", TextBox1.Text)
    da.Fill(ds, "salesreport")

    DataGridView1.DataSource = ds
    DataGridView1.DataMember = "salesreport"
```